# $facebook->getUser() return 0 in safari all the times and firefox sometimes

Tags: safari, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook application whiwh worked very good in one hoster.
Still we ave migrate the app in another hoster we have issues concerning this following code:

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
session_start();
require "facebook-facebook-php-sdk-5ba36bc/src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

All the time in Safari and sometimes in Firefox and Windows7, getUser() return 0!

Do you know why? What will be the solution?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Changing P3P is not resolving anything.

before:

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
```

after:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

and even this:

```
  header('P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"');
```

not fix this issue :( .

Another ideas?

Comment: Most definitely another incarnation of the old _third party cookies_ problem.

Comment: Cookies issues? So what is the solution or where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is where I said it was, and ways to solve or work around it are here on stackoverflow or the web. A little effort of your own, please.

Comment: I have already setted P3P header : header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"'); who worked with IE and now i have changed to: header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
Am i wold or hot in order to fix the issue? ^^

Comment: changing p3p nor resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by manually adding the domain to the **getloginURL**, (the same in your app config on facebook developers).Facebook was somehow getting bitchy about the cookies. Hope it helps!.

**PHP SDK**

```
$this->fb->getLoginUrl( array( 
    'domain'=>'http://mysite.com',
    'scope' => $this->scope,
    'redirect_uri' => $endpoint,
    'display' => 'popup' 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: I don't call getLoginUrl so i don't adapt the code with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Just change your php header to

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"');
```